# Understanding Windows Speech API

Tags: c++, windows, text-to-speech, sapi

I want to send a SSML for TTS synthesis.

I try to make the call on the TTS Client application:

```
CComPtr<ISpVoice> pVoice;
pVoice->Speak(ssml, SPF_ASYNC | SPF_PARSE_SSML, NULL);
```

This is the correct way for synthesis a SSML?

I'm implementing the SAPI Voice too.

I implement the following interfaces: `ISpTTSEngine`, `ISpObjectWithToken`. But when I send with the flag `SPF_PARSE_SSML` set, the `ISpObjectWithToken::SetObjectToken` is called, but the `ISpTTSEngine::Speak` isn't show!

My implementation is similar to this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6190/Creating-Microsoft-SAPI-Compliant-Application-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two problems.

SAPI doesn't accepts SSML. It's support SSML tags. I cannot send a full SSML.

Using `SPF_PARSE_SSML` doesn't means that the `Speak` action will be done.